# C# lambda group query with two parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

How to get count of cars that are turning in only one side, and count of cars that are turning in both sides using [lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx)?

```
    public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Car(int _Id, string _Name)
        {
            Id = _Id;
            Name = _Name;
        }
    }

    public class Turn
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Turn(int _Id, string _Name)
        {
            Id = _Id;
            Name = _Name;
        }
    }

    public class CarTurn
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Car Car { get; set; }
        public Turn Turn { get; set; }

        public CarTurn(int _Id, Car _Car, Turn _Turn)
        {
            Id = _Id;
            Car = _Car;
            Turn = _Turn;
        }
    }
```

.

```
Car car1 = new Car(1, "VW");
Car car2 = new Car(2, "Volvo");
Car car3 = new Car(3, "BMW");

Turn left = new Turn(1, "Left");
Turn right = new Turn(2, "Right");

CarTurn ct1 = new CarTurn(1, car1, left);
CarTurn ct2 = new CarTurn(2, car1, right);
CarTurn ct3 = new CarTurn(3, car2, right);
CarTurn ct4 = new CarTurn(4, car3, left);

List<CarTurn> data = new List<CarTurn>();
data.Add(ct1);
data.Add(ct2);
data.Add(ct3);
data.Add(ct4);
```

in this case result should be:

One side: 2 
Both Sides: 1

EDIT

```
var groups = data.GroupBy(x => x.Car.Id);
var bothSides = groups.Count(g=> g.Any(x=> x.Turn.Id == 1) && g.Any(x=> x.Turn.Id == 2));
var oneSide = groups.Count(g=> (g.Any(x=> x.Turn.Id == 1) && !g.Any(x=> x.Turn.Id == 2))
                            || (!g.Any(x=> x.Turn.Id == 1) && g.Any(x=> x.Turn.Id == 2)));
```

this is returning:

bothSides: 1 
oneSide: 0

Comment: You probably want to group the turns by car, and count the elements in  the group... possibly then grouping by that count. What have you tried so far?

Comment: could you provide more info of the class `CarTurn`?

Comment: Why the lambda syntax?  Start by looking at Group syntax.  You want to filter your turns, group all the turns by car, then return the cars.  A little sample code to show what you're trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: CarTurn has to have some public properties for Linq to inspect.  Using properties in the creator doesn't mean they are accessible outside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var carTurns = new[] { ct1, ct2, ct3, ct4 };
var groupedCarTurns = carTurns.GroupBy(ct => ct.Car);
var oneSideCount = groupedCarTurns.Count(group =>
    group.All(ct => ct.Turn == right) ||
    group.All(ct => ct.Turn == left);
var bothSides = groupedCarTurns.Count(group =>
    group.Any(ct => ct.Turn == right) &&
    group.Any(ct => ct.Turn == left);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (property names imagined):

```
var groups = data.GroupBy(x => x.CarId);
var bothSides = groups.Count(g=> g.Any(x=> x.IsLeftTurn) && g.Any(x=> x.IsRightTurn);
var oneSide = groups.Count(g=> (g.Any(x=> x.IsLeftTurn) && !g.Any(x=> x.IsRightTurn))
                                || (!g.Any(x=> x.IsLeftTurn) && g.Any(x=> x.IsRightTurn);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't use XOR for oneSide?